# c#: No service for type *Context has been registered. Database connection issue

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I am new in C# and try to add the database connection to the MVC project with ASP.NET core:

### Model:

- Entity class **User**:

  ```
  public class User
  {
      public string Name { get; set;}
      public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Context:

  ```
  using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

  namespace Forum.Models
  {
      public sealed class ForumContext : DbContext
      {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set;}

        public ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
             optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=password;database=forum1;");
        }
    }
  }
  ```
- Class - initializer:

  ```
   public static class SampleData
   {
     public static void Initialize(ForumContext context)
     {
       if (!context.Users.Any())
       {
           context.Users.AddRange(
               new User()
               {
                   LastName = "last name",
                   Name = "Name"
               }
               );
       }
     }
   }
  ```

### Configuration and executing:

- appsettings.json:

  ```
  {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=password;database=forum1"
    },
    "Logging": {
     "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
   },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
   }
  ```
- in the class **Sturtup.cs** I modified only `ConfigureService` method for MySqlConnection injection:

  ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ => new MySqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]));
    }
  ```
- and class **Program.cs:**

  ```
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            IServiceProvider provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
  //-------------------ERROR----------------------------
                var context = provider.GetRequiredService<ForumContext>();//there is the exception was throwed 
                SampleData.Initialize(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
            }
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
  }
  ```
- installed packages:

[image]

In the result I have the following error:

[image]

---

Comment: you haven't regestered your ef core dbcontext.

Comment: Why this question is so bed? I just following to guide and got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like below in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<{yourDBContext_Name}>(options =>
{
      options.UseMySql({Your Connection String});
      // If it is for Sql Server use options.UseSqlServer({Your Connection String});
});
```

Comment: If you look carefully at the question you will notice that OP is using MySql not Sql Server

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 
Now I got error `Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces...`

Comment: that is a different error, please check if the reference to `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` are correct

Comment: Thank, resolved! I only added `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` into project and all works well (and modified User entity since the Id field also needed)